# waitTime not respected when Expected Condition fails in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I have the following sample code:

```
try:
  element_found = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH,'//div[@class='sample-class']))
  print("Success")
except Exception:
  print("Failure")
```

When the element is located then the wait time of 10 seconds is honored and so the time taken to print `'Success' is <=10 seconds` but when the expected condition fails then the time taken to print `'Failure' is 50 seconds` consistently.

So why is the `10 seconds limit not honored` for a failure case? Why is it taking `50 seconds?`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Implicit wait as well in your code.

This is what officials has got to say about mixing of Implicit wait with explicit wait :

> **Warning:** Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait
> of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout
> to occur after 20 seconds.

[Reference link](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/)